# Flash binary socket communication with netty

Tags: flash, sockets, binary, netty

Can some body point me to make a flash binary socket client, for netyy server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find numerous examples of this on the net, anyway pasting some code tidbits here.

```
import flash.net.Socket;
private var remoteHost:String;
private var portNumber:int;

// Create a new Socket object and assign event listeners.
socket = new Socket();
socket.addEventListener(Event.CONNECT, connectHandler);
socket.addEventListener(Event.CLOSE, closeHandler);
socket.addEventListener(ErrorEvent.ERROR, errorHandler);
socket.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, ioErrorHandler);
```

A function to connect to netty server

```
public function connect():Boolean
    {
        // Load policy file from remote server.
        //Security.loadPolicyFile("xmlsocket://" + remoteHost + ":" + policyPort);
        // Attempt to connect to remote socket server.
        try {
            trace("Trying to connect to " + remoteHost + ":" + portNumber + "\n");
            socket.connect(remoteHost, portNumber);
        } catch (error:Error) {
            /*
                Unable to connect to remote server, display error 
                message and close connection.
            */
            trace(error.message + "\n");
            socket.close();
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

A function that does login functionality to a netty game server that I created. You can ignore the login etc, just trying to show how it works with netty. To see the actual [java game server code goto github link](https://github.com/menacher/java-game-server) provided.

```
    private function connectHandler(event:Event):void {
        if (socket.connected) {
            socket.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.SOCKET_DATA, loginHandler);
                    var payLoad:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
            payLoad.writeByte(LOG_IN);//opcode sent back to netty server in my implementation
            payLoad.writeBytes(encodeMultiStrings(user, pass, roomName));// credentials
            trace("Payload length before encode is: " + payLoad.length);
            var login:ByteArray = encodeBytes(payLoad);
            trace ("Login bytes length: " + login.length);
            writeBytesToSocket(login);
        }else {
            trace("unable to connect\n");
        }
    }
```